# In Dos when is it too late to shout "Dos"?

Tags: dos

If a player lays out all their cards during their turn without calling Dos (technically ending the game), can another player call Dos on the player if they don’t notice during the time they are laying down the cards?

The game specified exact steps for when to move cards over and when to lay down bonus cards. We’ve been playing that we have until discarding to call Dos, but this doesn’t really give the other players an opportunity to call Dos in this situation. It’s happened a couple times now that Dos hasn’t been called because we’ve allowed that leeway for all other plays.

Now some feel this is unfair even though that was what was agreed in the beginning. However, cards are not moved to discard until the laying down is done so it really doesn’t work when going out. We see that needs to change, but the real question we are asking is:

Can someone call Dos after the game is technically over?
If they don’t call before the cards are laid down is it too late?

Answer (score 1):

From the way I am reading the rules you can call dos on another player up until the point that the round ends. As soon as a player plays their last card it is to late to call dos as that would cause the player to get more points.

[Offical Rules](https://www.mattelgames.com/sites/mattel_games/files/2018-03/FRM36-0970-G2_IS_web.pdf)

[Rules](https://www.unorules.com/dos-rules/)

Rules for calling dos

> Here is where Dos and Uno are similar. Once you have exactly TWO cards in your hand, remember to yell out “Dos". If you forget to shout “Dos" and are caught by another player (who says “Dos" before you do), you must draw 2 cards from the Draw pile as a penalty, but take note that you only draw the two cards at the END of your turn (when you are just about to end it).

End of round rules

> The first player who discards all his/her cards is the winner of the round. If the player earned any Double Color Match Bonuses during his/her turn, then all the other players should draw cards as well, before tallying up the points. The winner of the round gets to score points from all the cards in other player’s hands and become the dealer for the next round.

Comment: I agree, but you find the real rule book here: https://www.mattelgames.com/sites/mattel_games/files/2018-03/FRM36-0970-G2_IS_web.pdf

Comment: @OlaStröm Thanks for that link, I have added it but left in the other link as the official rules link does not appear to allow for copying the content.